# linked list program

Tags: c, linked-list

I am expecting the below linked list program to print `1`
but its not.can anyone figure out why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * link;
};

typedef struct node  NODE;
void display(NODE *);
void add(NODE *,int );

int main()
{
  NODE *head=NULL;
  add(head,1);
  display(head);
  printf("\n");
  getch();
  return 0;
}

void display(NODE *pt)
{
  while(pt!=NULL)
  {
    printf("element is");
    printf("%d",pt->data);
    pt=pt->link;
  }
}

void add(NODE *q,int num)
{
  NODE *temp;
  temp = q;
  if(q==NULL)
  {
    q=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp = q;
  }
  else
  {
    while((temp=temp->link)!=NULL);
    temp->link = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=temp->link;
  }

  temp->data = num;
  temp->link  = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and stepping through and seeing what the contents of your link list structures are at each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` method when called first time (when `head == NULL`) should add the first node to the list thus changing `head` to point to the newly allocated node.

But this does not happen as `add` does not communicate back the changed `head` to the caller.

To fix this you can either return the modified `head` from the function:

```
// call as before but assign the return value to head.
head = add(head,1);

.....

// return type changed from void to NODE *
NODE* add(NODE *q,int num)
{
    // make the changes as before

    // return the head pointer.  
    return q;
}
```

or you can pass the pointer `head` by address to the function `add` as:

```
// pass the address of head.
add(&head,1);

.....

// change type of q from NODE * to NODE **
void add(NODE **q,int num)
{
  // same as before but change q to *q.

  // any changes made to the list here via q will be visible in caller.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your local variable `head` in `main()` is not modified by your `add()` function. This means you are calling `display()` with a parameter of NULL.

You'll need to pass a `NODE **q` into add, then update it in add().

Comment: i.e. it's passed by value, not reference. Alternatively you could return the new value of `head` and always use `head = add(head, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The add() function is modifying the q argument, but it is passing it by value. Then head remains NULL after the add() call.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in signature of add method, to make your program work you should pass pointer to pointer of NODE, like this

```
void add(NODE **,int );
```

and work with him.
Then in case

```
if(*q==NULL)
```

you can allocate memory and replace NULL pointer to new HEAD
by it

```
*q=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

So it will work.

The problem is when you allocate memory you just replace local copy of null pointer to NODE but it doesn't affect head in main function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
  NODE *head=NULL;
  add(head,1);
  display(head);
```

NODE *head is local to main.  It's value is NULL.  You pass the *value* NULL to add, which then creates a NODE and sets its data to 1.  You then return to main... ...where head is *STILL* NULL.  You need to pass the address of head, so that it's actual value is changed in add().  You also need to change add() to work with a pointer.

Main should return EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE.  Don't typedef struct node; it's harmful to readability and you get no abstraction here from using it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Add the new head pointer never gets returned. So it still points to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... you're getting tripped up by the pointers...
Essentially, if you want to modify "head", you need to send a reference to THAT... otherwise you are just modifying the pointer... Change your code to this:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<conio.h> 

struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node * link; 
}; 

typedef struct node NODE; 
void display(NODE *); 
void add(NODE **,int ); 

int main() 
{ 
    NODE *head=NULL; 
    add(&head,1); 
    display(head); 
    printf("\n"); 
    getch(); 
    return 0; 
} 

void display(NODE *pt) 
{ 
    while(pt!=NULL) 
    { 
        printf("element is "); 
        printf("%d",pt->data); 
        pt=pt->link; 
    } 
} 

void add(NODE **q,int num) 
{ 
    NODE *temp; 
    temp = *q; 
    if(*q==NULL) 
    { 
        *q=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        temp = *q; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        while((temp=temp->link)!=NULL); 
            temp->link = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
            temp=temp->link; 
    } 

    temp->data = num; 
    temp->link = NULL; 
}
```